Send SFMC Mobile Push only to device that has a certain tag
I have mobile application, where it is possible to set preferences for the types of push notifications users receive per device (every device can have different preferences).
We are using mobile push tags to organize these preferences.
The architecture of the SFMC mobile push is structured in a way that these preferences/tags are applied at the device level. Consequently, if a user has multiple devices (e.g., Device 1 and Device 2), they may have different preferences on each device. This setup is ok and consistent with our needs.
However, the issue arises when we segment based on a specific tag: SFMC selects all contacts that have this tag on any of their devices. It then sends the push message to all devices associated with the contact, regardless of whether each individual device has the tag.
For example, if a contact has Tag A on Device 1 but not on Device 2, and we create a target group for devices with Tag A, SFMC identifies that contact as a match based on Device 1. However, it sends the push notification to both Device 1 and Device 2 without verifying if Device 2 has the same tag. This behaviour is not aligned with my needs where I want push notifications to be sent only to the specific device(s) with the relevant tag. (neither it seems consistent with the architecture where tags are applied on device level).
Is it possible within SFMC to restrict mobile push notifications to only the specific device that has the desired tag? (It would be logical for the system to avoid sending messages to devices that do not meet the tag criteria, ensuring that users only receive relevant communications on the appropriate device).

To my knowledge, the only way to target a specific device is as follows (I haven't tested this, but it should help you get started):

Query the _PushTag Data View to get the relevant Device Tokens:

SELECT 
    pa.SystemToken as 'DeviceToken'
FROM 
    _PushAddress pa
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM _PushTag pt
        WHERE pt.DeviceID = pa.DeviceID
          AND pt._Value = 'specific_tag_value'
    )


Create a script activity to call the messageContact API (batch them per 5000 device tokens) to send Push Notifications to the device tokens obtained in the previous step.


Thank you @stijn-hoste, I will try it out and follow up with the results.
